# Unshortened HTTP URL extraction

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
data = pd.read_json('nfile.json')
urls=data['url']
def expand_url(url):
if url is None:
  return ''

  r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
  try:
      return r.headers['location']
  except KeyError:
      return ''
expanded_url = urls.apply(expand_url)
```

By using this code I can extract HTTPS links, not HTTP links. When I try using this to get http links unshortened I am redirecting the same shortend URL.
For example, if I use this URL 'http shortened url' I want to get this 'http unshortened url' but I am getting 'https shortened url' this as result.

```
{
"id": 89195392,
"id_str": "89195392",
"name": "Hany Al-Sonbaty",
"screen_name": "HanySonbaty",
"location": "Cairo",
"description": "Founder of @SawariVentures & @Flat6Labs",
"url": "http: shortened url",
"entities": {
  "url": {
    "urls": [
      {
        "url": "http: shortened url ",
        "expanded_url": "http://www.sawariventures.com",
        "display_url": "sawariventures.com",
        "indices": [
          0,
          22
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": {
    "urls": []
  }
},
"protected": false,
"followers_count": 7506,
"friends_count": 3401,
"listed_count": 127,
```

This is the JSON file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OkJFfHyU4Eb-V3mrU2qJ_jwBaQQkunJa/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre], specifically with actual examples of URLs. As it stands it's difficult to tell what your issue is.

Comment: Please also fix your indentation.

Comment: There are no "http shortened urls" in your JSON file, just https...

Comment: Check the above example if i use the shortened url from the url section iam getting that shortened url as output thats my problem iam not getting the unshortened one.in the example the unshortened url is starting with http not https.when i use this function i got the unshortened url if the url on expanded url section is starts with https.and also i have a record of 16k profile so iam getting connection timeout error sometimes how to resolve it also.